# gameover function is ignores the if statement twine sugarcube

Tags: html, if-statement, adventure, twine, sugarcube

still working on an adventure game. I've put the gameover if statement in all html files/chapters

```
 <<if $breath <1>><<goto "gameover">>
 <<elseif $happiness <1>><<goto "recovery>>
 <</if>>

breath  <progress @value="$breath" max="100"></progress>
happiness  <progress @value="$happiness" max="100"></progress>
credits  <progress @value="$credits" max="100"></progress>
```

before it was on the bottom of the page, but then it wasn't working properly, not executing when breath was empty.

now I´m not able to play anymore because I'm directly directed to the gameover page, even when the breath count is 100...

I reset the breath variable every restart/start of the game in an rest html:

```
<<set $credits to 100>> 
<<set $happiness to 100>> 
<<set $breath to 100>>
<<goto "start">>
```

then in the next chapter you are still able to play (even with the gameover if statement in there) but afterwards you land always at gameover... why?

I'm using twine sugarcube.

Comment: what version of sugarcube? what is `<1>`? do you mean `if $breath is 0`?

Comment: yes i mean when it is less then 1.

Comment: it´s version SugarCube – v2.36.1

Comment: [mcve] of whole code would probably be helpful, where gameover is in relation to reset, etc

Answer (score 1):

I believe based on [documentation](https://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/#:%7E:text=TwineScript%20conditional%20operators%3A) you need `lt` (less than). The next section has js though so maybe its spacing `< 1>>` not `<1>>`

```
<<if $breath lt 1>><<goto "gameover">>
<<elseif $happiness lt 1>><<goto "recovery>>
```